# Any potential problems with masses of conditions for a lock in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, conditional-statements

First some background: In Java all the constructs for conditional waiting allows for spurious wakeups which can mess with fairness. I've been toying with writing an implementation for a ReadWrite lock which serves the incoming threads in strict order-of-arrival.

Now, my algorithm creates a new java.util.concurrent.Condition each time a thread enters the class I've written. I wonder whether this kind of behavior is advisable or if there are some bad side effects of this kind of patterns, like massive slowdown.

Comment: Question: Why can't us use the Java fair lock. (new ReentrantLock(boolean fair)) ?

Comment: The fundamental problem is that waiting on conditions suffers from spurious wakeups which can mess with things pretty badly. Using fair locks doesn't help agains spurious wakeups unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Well, like all performance issues you should generally try it the clean way first and then test. That being said creating and GCing short lived objects – even a lot of them – is what JVMs are particularly good at.